# Getting elements form object [1] and place it all on object [0] javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, vuex

So I have a payload that pushes firestore collection to an object. Currently when I console.log the object, it shows:

[image]

I need it to be in just 1 array, how do I go about that?

I need it to look like (image below) so I can use it with my vuetify data tables

[image]

My vuex goes like this:

```
  mutations: {
    firebaseOrders(state, payload) {
      state.firebaseOrders.unshift(payload)
    },

  actions: {
    getFireBaseOrders(state) {
      db.collection("orders").onSnapshot((res) => {
        const changes = res.docChanges();
        changes.forEach((change) => {

          // Push all data to firebaseOrders[]
          let payload = change.doc.data();
          state.commit("firebaseOrders", payload);
 ...
```

Comment: `I need it to be in just 1 array, how do I go about that` ... what do you want one array?

Comment: Yes!! Just one array, like the second image.

Comment: You can make any reference as in `new_array = old_array[0]`. Not understanding why this a question

Answer (score 0):

This joins the two arrays together.

```
new_array = old_array[0].concat(old_array[1])
```

[Reference: MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)